# How to draw a Heatmap along streets only

Tags: math, maps, openstreetmap, heatmap

Given a single point on a Map, how can I draw a heatmap along streets around it, which represents its driving-distance from the known point?

Comment: Did you already read about [Isochrones](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Isochrone)?

Comment: no I haven't. Thank, helps a lot